# open a link within an iframe in the same tab

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am trying to click on a link that is within iframe in Cypress. The link opens in the next tab and the test fails.

```js
cy.get('iframe.body').wait(1000).its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .find('a').contains('Click').click();
```

To fix the issue used something like this to make the new page open on the same tab. But its not working:

```js
cy.get('iframe.body').wait(1000).its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .find('a').contains('Click')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click();
```

Element looks something like this:

```html
<iframe class="body" data-flexie-id="3" data-flexie-parent="true" src="messages/1.html" style="">
</iframe>
<p>
  <a href="https://Thisisalink/91cf-a6c3792a5cc5" target="_blank">Click</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`target="_parent"` opens the link in the same page as the parent.
Edit: I suppose you don't want the `<a>` to be in the `<iframe>`, right?

```
<iframe class="body" data-flexie-id="3" data-flexie-parent="true" src="messages/1.html" style=""></iframe>
<p><a href="https://Thisisalink/91cf-a6c3792a5cc5" target="_blank">Click</a></p>
```

Comment: I cannot change the html code. Think i should manage the test. How can i use cypress to get it in the same page?

Comment: I am sorry for my misunderstanding! 
The fact is that I don't see any 'target' in the iframe, but in the 'a'. This a is currently outside of the iframe. Is this maybe what creates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had found 2 solutions:

1. Copy the link and visit it:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("ui_clickTagButton", (buttonSelector) => {
    cy.log('ui_clickTagButton - start')

    cy.wrap(buttonSelector)
        .should('have.prop', 'href')
        .then(href => cy.visit(href))

    cy.log('ui_clickTagButton - End')
})
```

2. [Remove the target attribute](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) using the Jquery - incorporated in cypress, then click:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("ui_removeATagTargetAttributeAndCick", (aTagSelector) => {
    cy.log('ui_clickAnchorTagButton')
    cy.get(aTagSelector)
        .then((aTagElement) => {
            Cypress.$(aTagElement).removeAttr("target");
            cy.get(aTagElement)
                .click({force: true})
                .should('not.exist')
        })
})
```

So for your case I would Use the second one:

```
cy.get('iframe.body').wait(1000).its('0.contentDocument.body').find('a')
   .then(button => {
       cy.ui_removeATagTargetAttributeAndCick(button)
   })
```

Comment: Thanks @Rosen Mihaylov. The first option worked for me. Though, i see that there is error with the visit - No overload matches this call.

Comment: Overload 1 of 2, '(url: string, options?: Partial<VisitOptions>): Chainable<AUTWindow>', gave the following error.Argument of type 'JQuery<HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Overload 2 of 2, '(options: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string; }): Chainable<AUTWindow>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'JQuery<HTMLAnchorElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: string; }'.
Property 'url' is missing in type 'JQuery<HTMLAnchorElement>' but required in type '{ url: string; }'.ts(2769)cypress.d.ts(2023, 46): 'url' is declared here.

Comment: visit(url: string, options?: Partial<VisitOptions>): Chainable<AUTWindow>
    visit(options: Partial<VisitOptions> & { url: any}): Chainable<AUTWindow>

Comment: Have the above two in the cypress.d.ts file not sure if there is an option to pass element instead of the url

Comment: Have not seen such options and errors - not sure about them, but I usualy make a `cy.wait(4000)` after a visit to consider render time before continuing the test

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML indicates the link is outside the `iframe`, if so you don't need to select it.

Using `.find('a')` is similar to `.within(() => ...)`, but since `<a>` is not within the `iframe`, your strategy to remove the target will work if you target the `<a>` directly

```
cy.contains('a', 'Click')  
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
  .click();
```